# The input keeps looping after I put the right value

Tags: python

```
import random

word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

random_word = random.choice(word_list)
print(random_word)

display = ["_" for _ in random_word]
guess = ''

for i in range(len(random_word)):
    while guess in random_word[i]:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
        if random_word[i] == guess:
            display[i] = random_word[i]
            print(" ".join(display))
```

I was expecting that it won't ask the same question 2 times after it prints the value in the empty space.

This is the output of the code:

```
camel
Guess a letter: c
c _ _ _ _
Guess a letter: a
Guess a letter: a
c a _ _ _
Guess a letter: m
Guess a letter: m
c a m _ _
Guess a letter: e
Guess a letter: e
c a m e _
Guess a letter: l
Guess a letter: l
c a m e l
```

Comment: it looks like the `while` loop is supposed to be on the outside, and the `for` loop should start after the `input`.

Comment: You can use the debug of pycharm or use the ipdb package breakpoint to see why it is output twice, this should be an easy problem to solve.The most important thing about programming is hands-on practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are replacing the "guess" before comparing:

```
...
guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
if random_word[i] == guess:
...
```

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(random_word)):
    while guess in random_word[i]:
        if random_word[i] == guess:
            display[i] = random_word[i]
            print(" ".join(display))
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
```

A better version:

```
display = ["_" for _ in random_word]
guess = ''
while "_" in display:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    for i in range(len(random_word)):
        if random_word[i] == guess:
            display[i] = random_word[i]
    print(" ".join(display))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Lol I'm still learning. 

Comment: This community is here to help. Just remember to accept one answer that satisfies the question, to remove the question from unanswered questions .

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to keep asking the user for the next letter until they guessed correctly, the condition for the `while` loop should be `guess != random_word[i]`, not `guess in random_word[i]`.

"Repeat this as long as the guess is *not equal* to the correct letter."